# Android Contact Images

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am having android jelly bean 4.2.2 on my phone. Inside the contacts app, When I try add an image for a contact a pop up comes with two options

1. Take a photo
2. Choose from gallery

When I choose from gallery, It is opening dropbox instead of gallery app on android. How to add contacts from my phones gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not looking for code version.  Just got to Settings->Application Manager->Dropbox->clear defaults

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
private void selectImage(){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getParent().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

I utilise this in my app and it will prompt the user to choose from either gallery,dropbox,googledrive,etc. depending on what apps you already installed.

To process the selected image you can explore on :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
```

detect the defined request code.

Hope that helps